# codeigniter insert date into database which is sent fom post method

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

in my date input field in the form I get date using date picker. Now I need to know how can I save that particular date in the database table,I don't know how to access date at the model.

this is form field

```
Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
```

this is model

```
function save_cheque(){

    $insert_cheque_data = array(

        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'amount' => $this->input->post('amount'),
        'amount_letters' => $this->input->post('amount_in_words'),
        'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
        'account_no' => $this->input->post('acc_no'),
        'bank' => $this->input->post('bank'),
        'date' => $this->input->post('date'),
             ); 

        $this->db->insert('cheque_details',$insert_cheque_data);

        $this->load->database();
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM companydetails");
        return $query->result();        

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to give that form field a `name` just like any other form field. The datepicker will populate it with a value for you.

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker"/>
```

You access it in your PHP normally:

```
'date' => $this->input->post('date'),
```

Comment: then what should be data type in database??

Comment: Ideally it would be date or datetime depending on the value of the date.